# React calendar not rendering styles

Tags: reactjs, styles

in reactjs react-calendar not rendering properly it looks like a table. it not displaying well[it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFkfi.png)   how I fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The styles can be imported by adding the following import to your file:

```
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';
```

Comment: I added the above line in my component file but still it is not rendering properly. Can you please help?

Comment: Did you try a hard refresh in your browser? And please double check that the package is installed correctly and doesn't show error messages in the console @newbie

Comment: No, neither any error is shown and I have refreshed as well. The import statements doesnt give any error. but when I inspect the `Calendar`, it shows `react-calendar` class applied to it but stylings of `react-calendar` are not there. There is some configuration issue, I guess. but I am using the first webpack config https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/